# draw resonance plot with pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots

I want to draw a plot like this [image]

Here is my tex

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
$x = \hat{x}\cdot\frac{\omega_0^2}{\sqrt{\left(\omega_0^2-\omega_E^2\right)^2+4\cdot \delta^2 \cdot \omega_E^2}}$\\

\begin{tikzpicture}
        % Plot Function
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=8,
            xmax=35,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=25,
            ]
            % \delta
            \def\kd{0.82}
            % \omega_0
            \def\kw{16.9}
            % \hat{x}
            \def\kx{2}
            \addplot[samples=500, very thick] {\kx*\kw^2/(sqrt{(\kw^2-x^2)^2+4*\kd^2*x^2})};
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And I get

[image]

but I expect (plotted the same function with EXCEL)

[image]

Comment: What's the problem? Perhaps you should add a screenshot of your codes result? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmin=8, xmax=35,
ymin=0, ymax=25,
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\kd}{0.82}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\kw}{16.9}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\kx}{2}
\addplot[domain=0:35, samples=200, very thick, smooth] {\kx*\kw^2/(sqrt((\kw^2-x^2)^2+4*\kd^2*x^2))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with one peak]